# How to pass comma seperated values in IN where clause

Tags: proc

I want to ask how to pass the '30','31','32' to SQL WHERE IN clause For example

EXEC SQL DECLARE abcd CURSOR FOR SELECT Consignment FROM Transaction WHERE order_type IN (:dest)

where dest will hold the value '30','31','32'.

I have tried as above example but it is not working SQL did not return any result.

Comment: Are you aware of *any* language that will, without prompting, on a function being passed a single string parameter, decide to inspect the contents of that parameter, find commas, and instead automatically treat it as *multiple* parameters? I'm not aware of any, and SQL certainly isn't one.

Comment: I have created the dest as , when I print dest I am getting as '30','31','32'

Comment: I want to ask how to pass the '30','31','32'  to                                        EXEC SQL DECLARE abcd CURSOR FOR
SELECT Consignment FROM Transaction WHERE order_type IN (:dest)      where dest will hold the value '30','31','32'

Comment: Using the question title in your favourite search engine will return useful methods for doing this. Alas, there is no 'standard' or 'easy' way. e.g. [Using comma separated value parameter strings in SQL IN clauses](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/584680/Using-comma-separated-value-parameter-strings-in-S)

Comment: Thanks for your comment .I also would like to tell you,here dest is C string like, char dest[20]={"'30','31','32'."}, which i am passing as order_type IN (:dest).

Comment: Something like  1  declare
      l_deptnos  varchar2(100) := '10,20';
      l_rc       sys_refcursor;
      l_dept_rec dept%rowtype;
    begin
      open l_rc for 'select * from dept where deptno in (' || l_deptnos || ')';
      loop
        fetch l_rc into l_dept_rec;
        exit when l_rc%notfound;
       dbms_output.put_line( l_dept_rec.dname );
     end loop;
     close l_rc;
  end;
But i want to implement in proc like 
EXEC SQL DECLARE abcd CURSOR FOR SELECT Consignment FROM Transaction WHERE order_type IN (:dest)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way.split the data on seperator(,), insert into a table in a while loop. Then "IN (select "column_name" from temp table)". Now split and insert into a temp table is a tricky thing.

```
DECLARE @StringToSeperate VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @StringToSeperate = '1,2,5'

--SELECT @StringToSeperate IDs INTO #Test


CREATE TABLE #valus (ID int) 

DECLARE @CommaSeperatedValue VARCHAR(255) = ''
DECLARE @Position INT = LEN(@StringToSeperate)

--Add Each Value
WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @StringToSeperate) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @Position  = CHARINDEX(',', @StringToSeperate)  
    SELECT @CommaSeperatedValue = SUBSTRING(@StringToSeperate, 1, @Position-1)

    INSERT INTO #valus 
    SELECT @CommaSeperatedValue

    SELECT @StringToSeperate = SUBSTRING(@StringToSeperate, @Position+1, LEN(@StringToSeperate)-@Position)

END

--Add Last Value
IF (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@StringToSeperate)))>0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #valus
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@StringToSeperate, 1, @Position)
END

SELECT ID FROM #valus
```

Comment: I can  give an example tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks barun for your example but I need the code in proc ....as per ur code DECLARE @StringToSeperate VARCHAR(10) ... @ is not support in pro*c

Comment: Its a Tsql syntax. which db you are working on ?  you can always change the syntax acording to your database.

Comment: I am working on pro*c ...I am trying to change in pro*c but if you aware of proc can you please give any example.

Comment: you can always post the proc. and I can review

Comment: main()                                                                                                                {char send[3][3] = {"30","31","32"};                                                               status = foo(send);} foo((char** res)){}                                                                                                                                   
EXEC SQL DECLARE abcd CURSOR FOR SELECT Consignment FROM Transaction WHERE order_type IN (:res) ;                                           This gives only  records for order_type =30 and skip 31,32

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81145/discussion-between-pri-and-barun).

Comment: there are restriction in my network. I can't do chat :(  . lets talk when I get home .